# Angular CLI stoppped creating new project without any error

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular6

I'm trying to create a new project using angular cli but it looked like it is stuck in extracting and it does not generate any error:

```
D:\Angular6Sample\Angular6Sample>ng new angular6web --skip-git --skip-tests
CREATE angular6web/angular.json (4127 bytes)
...
CREATE angular6web/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (307 bytes)
CREATE angular6web/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
[            ......] \ extract:@angular/compiler: sill extract @angular/compiler@^6.1.0 extracted to D:\Angular6Sample\Angular6Sample\angular6web\node_modules\.stagin
```

and I opened a new cmd window and tried to create a new project and it told me it is already exists:

```
D:\Angular6Sample\Angular6Sample>ng new angular6web --skip-git --skip-tests
ERROR! angular6web/angular.json already exists.
...
ERROR! angular6web/e2e/src/app.po.ts already exists.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

D:\Angular6Sample\Angular6Sample>
```

So I thought that my project is already created but just failed to respond properly in the first cmd window so I tried building it:

```
D:\Angular6Sample\Angular6Sample>cd angular6web

D:\Angular6Sample\Angular6Sample\angular6web>ng build
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "D:\\Angular6Sample\\Angular6Sample\\angular6web".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "D:\\Angular6Sample\\Angular6Sample\\angular6web".
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:132:40)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:43:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:29:22)
    at DoOperator.call (C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\tap.js:29:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:24:22)
    at C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeTo.js:22:31
    at Object.subscribeToResult (C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToResult.js:7:45)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:75:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (C:\Users\Prashant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\mergeMap.js:72:14)

D:\Angular6Sample\Angular6Sample\angular6web>
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `cd "your app name"`
2. `npm install`
3. `ng serve`

it that didn't work :

```
npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10661